# Google Script: MailApp.sendEmail to multiple addresses?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I have a script that is using the following script:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftManager, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  row.state = STATE_PENDING;
```

Howeverm I would like to also send the same mail to `row.shiftSupervisor`, this is probably something really simple that I've overlooked, but I figured someone here would know straight away what it was.

Cheers for your help :)

**Edit** - I tried to use:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftManager, row.shiftSupervisor, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
      row.state = STATE_PENDING;
```

But no joy.

**Edit 2** - I got it working with:

```
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftManager, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftSupervisor, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  row.state = STATE_PENDING;
```

Not the most graceful looking piece of code, but it does the job...

Comment: what do you mean by multiple variables?

Comment: Totally a mistake, I was mutlitasking (badly) and put something else in the title.

Comment: You will have to loop over multiple email addresses to send one email to them.

Comment: Yeah, I got it to work with: `MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftManager, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftSupervisor, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
  row.state = STATE_PENDING;` It's a bit clunky looking as far as code goes, but its doing the job.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The email addresses can be concatenated (joined together) using the plus sign with a comma in between each email address.  In JavaScript the plus sign can be used for addition OR joining strings.  The plus sign is both an addition operator and a string operator in JavaScript.  Strings are text, and if you use the plus sign to concatenate text strings then it's a string formula.

One solution would be:

```
var recipient = row.shiftManager + "," + row.shiftSupervisor;
MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});
```

In the above example, there are 4 parameters.  But `MailApp.sendEmail()` has multiple possible parameter structures.  The following example shows all of the settings put into an object, where the "to" key in the object is for the recipient.

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: recipient,
  cc: recipientsCC,
  subject: Subject,
  htmlBody: html
});
```

A complete example:

```
function sendToMultiple() {
  var message = "This is a test of HTML <br><br> Line two";
  
  var recipientsTO = "example@gmail.com" + "," + "example@yahoo.com";
  var recipientsCC = "example@gmail.com";
  var Subject = "Vacation Approval Request";
  var html = message;
  
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientsTO,
    cc: recipientsCC,
    subject: Subject,
    htmlBody: html
  });

}
```

Documentation with an example is at the following link:

[Google Documentation - MailApp.sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object))

Comment: Hey, thanks for this! It looks much better than my crudely put together solution. However, I keep getting a message "Missing : after property ID. (line 96, file "Approval")"

Comment: Hey again, thanks for your help with this. I had it working, but it appeared to be interfering with another part of the script. However, I figured out I could do   `MailApp.sendEmail(row.shiftManager + "," + row.shiftSupervisor, "Holiday Approval Request", "", {htmlBody: message});` thanks to the way you had it laid out. A bit more elegant than repeating the function over again! This is why scripting / coding while working a night shift is bad. Haha, you miss silly little things! Cheers again~

Comment: Glad you got it to work.  I'll update the answer with your solution also.  Please consider marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: Done, thanks for everything. At the risk of sounding slightly cheeky, I've also mailed you regarding another issue I've been having with a piece of code. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I'm doing it:

```
//check quota and log
const emailsLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
console.log( emailsLeft + " emails left in quota");

//get list of emails from spreadsheet itself
//filter out empty rows
const emails = getTab("Config").getRange("D2:D").getValues().map(function(el){ return el[0]; }).filter(function(el){ return el != '' });  

//send emails from NO_REPLY email, subject and HTML body
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: emails.join(","),
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: html,
  noReply: true
});

function getTab(name) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  return sheet.getSheetByName(name);
}
```

getTab() and other helper functions can be found here
https://github.com/tim-kozak/google-spreadsheet-helpers