# Sending existing messages with the gmail API

Tags: gmail, base64, gmail-api

I'm trying to write a script that uses the gmail API to forward messages from my inbox to new recipients.

[This](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) guide recommends sending the base64 encoded string for the e-mail. Presumably, I could get the existing e-mail using the [get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method with `format=raw`, edit the base64 encoding to change the recipients, and send the new message along.

The messages I'm sending are quite large (many attachments), so this process (of downloading a massive base64 string, decoding it, doing some regex substituion, re-encoding it, and then re-uploading it) will take a long time. It also seems very cumbersome to use regex to manipulate a MIME email message.

It seems that there should be an easier way...? Perhaps some way to do this directly via the API?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [MailApp.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body). You can use that script to send to multiple receivers so sending messagees to many people wont be that cumbersome.

```
// Send an email with two attachments: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF) and an HTML file.
 var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Insert any HTML content here', 'text/html', 'my_document.html');
 MailApp.sendEmail('a@example.com,b@example.com,c@example.com', 'Attachment example', 'Two files are attached.', {
     name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
     attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
 });
```

If you want additional samples, try this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355195/google-script-mailapp-sendemail-to-multiple-addresses).

Comment: Thanks for the links. This isn't quite what I'm looking for as I need to send messages that already exist (in my e-mail inbox) to new senders so this still requires me to pull the html body out of the base64 string representing the original message. This might be the only option though...