# Send email in Google Spreadsheets using cells' values row per row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically, I used this code to send an email to a desired recipient, using the data I have on specific cells.

Now, considering I want to send a mail row per row, based on their content, how could I dynamically code this? Literally, consider I've these rows with some order data, and at the end of each row I want to have a button where I can send to a specific recipient the details inside.

So, the code should work for each row based on their content. For example: in row 3, I have the order "X", at the end of the row the operator have to press this "send email" button with the order contained in the row 3, then in row 4 the same with row 4 data, etc... Any help?

Also, how do I link this code in cell, like a button?

PS: last but not least, if I have to send the order detail of that row to 2 email addresses, is this doable?

```
function sendEmails() {
// Fetch the email address
var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ordini").getRange("G3");
var orderRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ordini").getRange("C3");
var numorderRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Ordini").getRange("A3");
var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
var orderDetail = orderRange.getValues();
var numOrd = numorderRange.getValues();
// Send Alert Email.
var message = orderDetail;
var subject = 'Ordine num.' + numOrd;
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a "Send email" button to each row of a Google sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45890894/how-do-i-add-a-send-email-button-to-each-row-of-a-google-sheet)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Script: MailApp.sendEmail to multiple addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355195/google-script-mailapp-sendemail-to-multiple-addresses)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that do exactly what you want. This function will read the email, order detail and order number from the selected row and will later send an email to both: the email on the row and a second email chosen by you. It will use the method [`offset()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset,-columnoffset) to read the values of the row based on the selected mail. This is the function:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var emailAddress = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    .getActiveCell().getValue();
  var orderDetail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    .getActiveCell().offset(0, 1).getValue();
  var numOrd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
    .getActiveCell().offset(0, 2).getValue();    
  var subject = 'Ordine num.' + numOrd;

  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress + ", second@mail.com", subject,
    orderDetail);
}
```

As you can see, I used the same variable names as your code. You will have to substitute `second@mail.com` with the desired second mail (other that the one on the row). Before using this function, you will have to link it to a button in the sheet. There is no need to use one button per row, just one button is enough. To do it follow these steps:

1. On the sheet, go to `Insert  Image  Image over cells` to
   embed a picture that will work as a button.
2. Select the picture and click on `⋮  Assign a script` and write on
   the dialog box the name of the desired function without brackets (in the previous
   code that would be `sendEmails`).

Now everything is set up. To make it work, you should select the email cell of the desired row and click on the button. A mail will be sent to both emails, with the desired subject and body. Please, do not hesitate to ask me to clarify anything if you still have any doubts.